# XML Imported Content is Empty Stock Data

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

hi im trying to scrape stock market data using google sheets

i am trying to get data the PRICE data from here
http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/PNB.xml

so in my google sheet i put
`=IMPORTXML("http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/PNB.xml","//*[@id='folder2']/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]")`

but i just get #NA and do not get any data

i have read that maybe it is not properly parsing the data so i also tried
`=index(IMPORTXML("http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/PNB.xml","//*[@id='folder2']"),1,1)`
but still no luck

any help would be appreciated

thanks

EDIT: i got the xml path by using google chromes right click -> copy -> copy xpath

Comment: Might be helpful to put the steps and the example XPath as a question and mark it as the answer. Explaining to others how to capture an XPath from Chrome and being able to see the difference from what you were trying, and marking the question as answered is helpful.

Comment: hi. i already did what you said.

Comment: No, you didn't. Don't edit the QUESTION to add the info, put it in as an ANSWER and click the check box to indicate that it satisfactorily answers the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: but there is still no answer to my question.. i am looking for an answer

Comment: I misunderstood what your edit meant. I thought you were indicating that obtaining the XPath from Google Chrome solved your problem.

Comment: no problem. haha.. we all make mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That resource is an XML file and the elements are bound to the namespace `http://phisix-api.appspot.com/phisix-stocks`.

```
<stocks xmlns="http://phisix-api.appspot.com/phisix-stocks" 
        as_of="2021-01-11T12:50:00+08:00">
    <stock symbol="PNB">
        <name>Phil Natl Bank</name>
        <price>
            <currency>PHP</currency>
            <amount>28.60</amount>
        </price>
        <percent_change>-1.55</percent_change>
        <volume>318800</volume>
    </stock>
</stocks>
```

It seems that Google Chrome copy XPath is providing the XPath to the rendered HTML  view of that XML, not the actual XML content.

The shortest and most simple XPath to target the `amount`, ignoring the namespace to avoid registering a namespace-prefix, is:

```
//*[local-name()="amount"]
```

Applying to the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/PNB.xml","//*[local-name()='amount']")
```

Answer (score -1):

or try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTDATA(A1), "amount>(.*)</amount")
```

[image]

Comment: regex over XML when there is XPath available is an awful idea